# VueJS multiple mixins

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an error in my script I do not know to fix. I want to import multiple mixins I created.

```
import GoogleMaps from '../mixins/GoogleMaps.js';
import MFApi from '../mixins/MFApi.js';

    export default {
        template: require('../templates/map.html'),
        mixins: [GoogleMaps, MFApi],
(...)
```

But this doesn't seem to work. How do I need to set the mixins variable properly if it is more than one?

As soon as I add the new mixin to the variable, the first one is not recognized anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you have a case like this. If you export a named module, not just by default, then you need to import it using curly braces.

In my mixin folder I have "regExpressions.js" file:

```
export const convertImage = {
  methods: {
   ...your methods here
  }
}
```

and "truncateString.js" file:

```
export default {
  methods: {
   ... your code here
  }
}
```

In my component I import my mixins.

```
import { convertImage } from "@/mixins/regExpressions";
import truncateString from "@/mixins/truncateString";

mixins: [truncateString, convertImage]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed the correct way to do it, I do this every day. When you say the mixin 'is not recognized', what does that mean. Perhaps you have a method or property by the same name in BOTH mixins - this this case, you have a conflict and the last passed conflicting method/property will survive, overwriting previous one(s) as they vue instance is compiled.